# make a chain combobox using JCombo

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, jcombobox

i would like to seek some help with my code because my current code wont work...i found this plugin code from this site [click here](http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/?lang=en)...as of now all are not working even the first combobox filtration...can anyone help me get this code work please.

[image]

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jCombo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jCombo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="position" id="position"></select>
<select name="salary_grade" id="salary_grade"></select>
<select name="salary" id="salary"></select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
   $("#position").jCombo({ url: "getPosition.php", selected_value : '150' } );
    $("#salary_grade").jCombo({ url: "getSalary_Grade.php?sgid=",
                    parent: "#position",
                    selected_value: '178'
                });     
    $("#salary").jCombo({ url: "getSalary.php?salaryid=",
                    parent: "#salary_grade",
                    selected_value: '630'
                });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

getPosition.php:

```
<?php

    // Connect Database
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");     
    mysql_select_db("test");

    // Execute Query in the right order  
    //(value,text)
    $query = "SELECT tcode, position FROM positions";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option = array("id" => $row[0], "value" => htmlentities($row[1]));
            $items[] = $option; 
        }        
    }
    mysql_close();
    $data = json_encode($items); 
    // convert into JSON format and print
    $response = isset($_GET['callback'])?$_GET['callback']."(".$data.")":$data; 
    echo $data;
?>
```

getSalary_Grade.php:

```
<?php

    // Connect Database 
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");     
    mysql_select_db("test");

    // Get parameters from Array
    $sgid = !empty($_GET['tcode'])
              ?intval($_GET['tcode']):0;

    // if there is no city selected by GET, fetch all rows    
    $query = "SELECT id,salary FROM salary_grades WHERE salary_grades.id = '$sgid'"; 

    //  fetch the results
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option = array("id" => $row[0], "value" => htmlentities($row[1]));
            $items[] = $option; 
        }        
    } 
    mysql_close();
    $data = json_encode($items); 
    $response = isset($_GET['callback'])?$_GET['callback']."(".$data.")":$data; 
    $cache->finish($response);  
?>
```

getSalary.php:

```
<?php

    // Connect Database 
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");     
    mysql_select_db("test");

    // Get parameters from Array
    $salaryid = !empty($_GET['id'])
              ?intval($_GET['id']):0;

    // if there is no city selected by GET, fetch all rows    
    $query = "SELECT id,salary FROM salarys WHERE salarys.id = '$salaryid'"; 

    //  fetch the results
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option = array("id" => $row[0], "value" => htmlentities($row[1]));
            $items[] = $option; 
        }        
    } 
    mysql_close();
    $data = json_encode($items); 
    $response = isset($_GET['callback'])?$_GET['callback']."(".$data.")":$data; 
    $cache->finish($response);  
?>
```

Comment: Is the problem in the PHP or JS code?

Comment: @Daniel Lisik i think the problem is in the JS code and the jquery.jCombo.min.js

Comment: http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/?lang=en

Comment: Try deleting `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jCombo.js"></script>` from you HTML code. Also, why don't you have `options` in you `select` tags?

Comment: @Daniel Lisik ok...and i just follow the instructions on the plugin example in this site http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/?lang=en

Comment: You want it to be like the last example (Nested Combos)?

Comment: @Daniel Lisik yes absolutely...but i cant make it work :(

Comment: Does the script at least select the default option on the first?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `$_GET['tcode']` in *getSalary_Grade.php* be `$_GET['sgid']` and `$_GET['id']` in *GetSalary.php* be `$_GET['salaryid']`?

Comment: @Daniel Lisik the first select only work after i read this http://phponlinesupport.com/can-t-figure-out-jquery-jcombo-t312373.html

Comment: and edit the jquery.jCombo.min.js according to the dude said

Comment: Did you edit *jquery.jCombo.min.js* on two places?

Comment: @Daniel Lisik what do you mean on two places?

Comment: it says `dataType:'jsonp'` in two places in the script.

Comment: @Daniel Lisik yea i edit it after that the first select worked but the 2nd and 3rd select still wont work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47447/discussion-between-daniel-lisik-and-xplody)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

**getSalary.php**

```
// Connect Database 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("klayton"); 

// Get parameters from Array 
$salaryid = !empty($_GET['salaryid']) 
?intval($_GET['salaryid']):0; 

// if there is no city selected by GET, fetch all rows 
$query = "SELECT id,salary FROM salarys WHERE id = $salaryid"; 

// fetch the results 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$items = array(); 
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$option = array("id" => $row['id'], "value" => htmlentities($row['salary'])); 
$items[] = $option; 
} 
}
```

**getSalary_Grades.php**

```
<?php 

// Connect Database 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("klayton"); 

// Get parameters from Array 
$sgid = !empty($_GET['sgid']) 
?intval($_GET['sgid']):0;

// if there is no city selected by GET, fetch all rows 
$query = "SELECT id, salary FROM salary_grades WHERE id = $sgid"; 

// fetch the results 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$items = array(); 
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$option = array("id" => $row['id'], "value" => htmlentities($row['salary'])); 
$items[] = $option; 
} 
}
```